# Pass global variable set with command button click to userForm VBA

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables, userform

So I have a command button on a sheet in my workbook that sets the value of a global variable stored in the `ThisWorkbook` module. Pressing the command button also initializes a `UserForm`. Upon initialization it is supposed to check the value of the global variable, `stuNameFormat`, but I can't seem to get it to fetch the value; instead it returns a null string. This is what I have tried:

My sub routine in the `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Public stuNameFormat As Integer

Sub reformatNames()
  
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

'   Pull data from hidden sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserFormInfo").Visible = True
    schoolYear = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserFormInfo").Range("A1").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserFormInfo").Visible = False
    Dim Year As String
    Year = schoolYear


'   Set sheet to current sheet
    Dim rosterSh As Worksheet
    Set rosterSh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim stuCount As Integer, lastStuRow As Integer, i As Variant
    Dim commaCount As Integer, periodCount As Integer
    stuCount = rosterSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row - 1
    lastStuRow = stuCount + 1
    commaCount = 0
    periodCount = 0

'   Count instances of commas and periods in range
    For Each i In rosterSh.Range("A2:A" & lastStuRow)
        If InStr(i.Value, ",") > 0 And InStr(i.Value, ".") > 0 Then
            commaCount = commaCount + 1
            periodCount = periodCount + 1
        ElseIf InStr(i.Value, ".") > 0 Then
            periodCount = periodCount + 1
        Else
            ' DO NOTHING - no comma or period in name!
        End If
    Next i

'   Check value of commaCount and periodCount to determine stuNameFormat
    If commaCount > 0 Then
        stuNameFormat = 1
    ElseIf commaCount = 0 And periodCount > 0 Then
        stuNameFormat = 2
    Else
        stuNameFormat = 3
    End If
    
    UserForm8.Show
End Sub
```

My sub routine in the `UserForm`:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    MsgBox "stuNameFormat is: " & stuNameFormat
End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please, place `Public stuNameFormat As Integer` in **a standard module**, where from it can be accessed from all modules. Or use it fully qualified: `ThisWorkbook.stuNameFormat = 1`...

Comment: Public variables should reside in a Standard Module so you can access them from anywhere in your app. No need to pass them around, it defies the purpose of having them.

Comment: ...and use `Option Explicit` so that the compiler can tell you that a variable is not known.